# 3d footprint (PCB) on PADS

Tags: power-supply, footprint

I have uploaded a feed imprint from Mouser electronics site. the symbol and the Footprint are good.

[image]

[image]

but when I look at the component in 3d on the software (pads logic and pads layout) I see the power supply as its:  (image)

[image]

Comment: What is your question?  Most Mouser / third-party symbols are square boxes with no real thought of inputs / outputs, so that's what I'd expect as a 3D model of the part.

Comment: I downloaded other footprints like capacities or other power and the 3D model is good. because when I looked at the 3D model of this components on their sites is in the form of a box. on the other hand on my file I find that it has a weird shape